# Can't SFTP to WPengine servers in Aptana, after they removed SSH cyphers

Tags: ssh, aptana

I used to be able to connect to WPengine just fine. However, The other day they removed the following SFTP/SSH cyphers: CBC, RC4, 3DES, MD5, and RIPEMD.

I went to Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2 > MAC methods and disabled MD5. Now it only uses sha1, sha2-256 and sha1-96. Still, I can't connect and I get this message: 'Establishing SFTP connection failed: The connection did not complete'

I don't know what else to do. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. A possible workaround is to use FileZilla though it doesn't come close to replacing Aptana.